# How to slice a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, slice

Ok, so I've got this string:

```
"MICROSOFT CORP CIK#: 0000789019 (see all company filings)"
```

And I would like to cut off everything after the `"CORP"` bit. How would I go about doing this in PHP? I am used to Python so I am not sure how this is done.

To be clear, this is the output I want:

```
"MICROSOFT CORP"
```

I am trying:

```
$companyname = substr($companyname, 0, strpos($companyname, " CIK"));
```

and I am getting nothing showing.

Here is my full code:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&match=&CIK=MSFT&filenum=&State=&Country=&SIC=&owner=exclude&Find=Find+Companies&action=getcompany');
$companyname = $html->find('span[class=companyName]', 0);
$companyname = substr($companyname, 0, strpos($companyname, " CIK#")+5);
$bizadd = $html->find('div[class="mailer"]');
echo $companyname;
echo "<br />";
foreach ($bizadd as $value) {
    $addvals = $value->find('span[class="mailerAddress"]');
    echo "<br />";
    foreach ($addvals as $value) {
        echo $value;
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Andrew, check my updated answer after your edits.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can either use `explode()` (http://php.net/explode) or a mix of `substr()` (http://php.net/substr) with `strpos()` (http://php.net/strpos).

```
<?php
$string = "MICROSOFT CORP CIK#: 0000789019 (see all company filings)";
$newString = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, " CIK#"));
echo $newString;
```

**Edit:** edited a few times to fit your question editing...

Comment: Er, this seems to cut off everything BEFORE CORP!

Comment: @AndrewAlexander: sorry, it wasn't clear enough in the question; updated the answer with the second option as well.

Comment: $newString = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, " CIK#")+5);

with $companyname substituted in for $newString didn't work either.

Comment: Hrm, maybe there's additional parts of it I can't see? I am pulling it from the HTML of a page. Could that be why it isn't working? Your example with setting the $string as the string in question worked fine. But the normal one I need isn't working

Comment: You will have to show a sample of an HTML and the script you wrote that didn't fetch the right string; I suggest looking for an answer first on HTML parsing, and if there is none to satisfy you open a new question, as this is a whole new subject. Good luck!

Comment: Got it, after I took a plaintext cut of the HTML

Answer (score 3):

You 'd find the position of `"CORP"` with [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) (be sure to read the giant red warning) and then cut off the relevant part with [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Answer (score 3):

I came to this page looking for a slice `slice($start, $end)` method, but only found case-specific solutions.

In my case, I only have indexes (start and end). The need for a `length` to slice a string seemed silly. So I wrote a slice function. It mimics JavaScript's [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method.

```
// str_slice(string $str, int $start [, int $end])
function str_slice() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    switch (count($args)) {
        case 1:
            return $args[0];
        case 2:
            $str        = $args[0];
            $str_length = strlen($str);
            $start      = $args[1];
            if ($start < 0) {
                if ($start >= - $str_length) {
                    $start = $str_length - abs($start);
                } else {
                    $start = 0;
                }
            }
            else if ($start >= $str_length) {
                $start = $str_length;
            }
            $length = $str_length - $start;
            return substr($str, $start, $length);
        case 3:
            $str        = $args[0];
            $str_length = strlen($str);
            $start      = $args[1];
            $end        = $args[2];
            if ($start >= $str_length) {
                return "";
            }
            if ($start < 0) {
                if ($start < - $str_length) {
                    $start = 0;
                } else {
                    $start = $str_length - abs($start);
                }
            }
            if ($end <= $start) {
                return "";
            }
            if ($end > $str_length) {
                $end = $str_length;
            }
            $length = $end - $start;
            return substr($str, $start, $length);
    }
    return null;
}


var_dump( str_slice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")          ); // "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var_dump( str_slice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5)       ); // "fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var_dump( str_slice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", -5)      ); // "vwxyz"
var_dump( str_slice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 40)      ); // ""
var_dump( str_slice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", -40)     ); // "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var_dump( str_slice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5, 10)   ); // "fghij"
var_dump( str_slice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5, 20)   ); // "fghijklmnopqrst"
var_dump( str_slice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5, 30)   ); // "fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var_dump( str_slice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", -20, 2)  ); // ""
var_dump( str_slice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", -20, 10) ); // "ghij"
var_dump( str_slice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", -20, 15) ); // "ghijklmno"
var_dump( str_slice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", -20, 40) ); // "ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort! The question is over 7 years old and I'm like 3 companies past where I was when I asked it! You should make this into a library available for people

Comment: I have a [repository](https://github.com/akinuri/php-lib) where I dump my scripts, and this is in [str_random.php](https://github.com/akinuri/php-lib/blob/master/str_random.php). I don't have the time to manage/restructure the files, so currently I just dump them there :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string is stored in $a, then any of

```
echo substr($a, 0, strpos($a, " CIK"));
```

or

```
preg_match("/(.*) CIK/", $a, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

or

```
echo preg_replace("/(.*) CIK.*/", "$1", $a);
```

will do.

Comment: $companyname = substr($companyname, 0, strpos($companyname, " CIK"));

Trying that, coming up with nothing.

Comment: @Andrew Alexander: probably a simple mistake. Are you sure your string contents are those that you indicated? If so, are you properly echoing the correct output?

Comment: As far as I know - how would I check and see if my string contains any more information that echo isn't showing? The string has a link in it - I imagine that might cause an issue?

Comment: I apologize for my general ignorance, I am new to slicing in PHP